# Socket is not working with angular build but working with full setup

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I have used socket in node and angular and also use the same version 2.3.1, it is working well when I have started ng serve, but when creating angular build then in build socket is not working.

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import {
  environment
} from '../../environments/environment';
import {
  Observable
} from "rxjs/Observable";
export class ChatService {
  private url = environment.socketApiPath;
  //'http://localhost:3000';
  private socket;
  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(this.url);
  }
  getChatMessages = () => {
    return new Observable < any > ((observer) => {
      this.socket.on('new_chatmessage', (response) => {
        observer.next(response);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show some code, what exactly you've written? Just an initial thought, it could have been an issue related to `https` on socket server.

Comment: ````constructor() {
        this.socket = io(this.url);
    }
    
    getChatMessages = () => {
        return new Observable<any>((observer) => {
            this.socket.on('new_chatmessage', (response) => {
                observer.next(response);
            });
        });
    }`````

Comment: Hello Ankit, what error you recieve on prod? You can check browser console for the same

Comment: not getting any error on console.

Comment: Can you check, whether you have `socketApiPath` property in `environment.prod.ts`?

Comment: yes its is wrong from environment.prod.ts, now wits is working thanks

Comment: I've added the same as a answer, please check, Accept mark as a accepted answer if it helped you. Thanks :) –

Answer (score 0):

Check your `socketApiPath` parameter in `environment.prod.ts` file. Basically this file is referred in `production` build

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  socketApiPath: 'url_here',
  ...
}
```